# Webmatrix - Image upload and post to DB

Tags: sql, image-processing, razor, webmatrix

I am trying to upload an image to my site, which works fine, but i am also trying to add the filename of that image to the database. Everything works, except a NULL value is passed into the database instead of the filename?

Code is :

```
@{  
Layout = "~/_template1.cshtml";
var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

//Get images
var imageget = "SELECT * FROM ImageInfo WHERE PropertyID='7'";

WebImage photo = null;
var newFileName = "";
var imagePath = "";
var imageThumbPath  = "";

if(IsPost){
    photo = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
    if(photo != null)
    {
        newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" +
            Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
        imagePath = @"images\property\" + newFileName;

        photo.Save(@"~\" + imagePath);
    }
    var imageput = "INSERT INTO ImageInfo (ImageURL) VALUES (@0)";
    db.Execute(imageput, Request["newFileName"]);
}
}
```

Comment: Never mind that you shouldn't accessing the database from within a view... Change `db.Execute(imageput, Request["newFileName"]);` to `db.Execute(imageput, newFileName);`

Comment: sorry dude, forgot to mention, im using Webmatrix Web Pages, not MVC, so accessing the db from here is the norm apparently! :s anyway, i'll try your suggestion out :)

Comment: Works great, thanks for all your help. How do i accept a comment as a correct answer? i'd like you to recieve the points for your help.

Comment: Added it as an answer. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `db.Execute(imageput, Request["newFileName"]);` to `db.Execute(imageput, newFileName);`